# Azure function precompiled multi function - same dll

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have followed this blog post to create a precompiled azure function.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/

Is it possible to create more than one function in the same project / same dll ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!

You'll need to add a new folder at the root of your project with your function name that contains a `function.json`.

Then, inside that `function.json` set `scriptFile` to your dll and `entryPoint` to the method which you want to act as your 2nd function.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\SomeDll.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionsLibraryProject.HelloHttpTrigger.SecondRunMethod",
  ...
}
```

Comment: How can we achieve this using VS 2017 precompiled functions, as we now have no way to add function.json manually

Comment: Precompiled functions, iirc, should do exactly what you want - wrap up all functions in one project into a single dll and automatically generate the above `function.json` properties